# UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated. Почему pandas не загружает данные(файл размером около 200мбайт) через read_pickle?

Tags: pandas, pickle

Код:

```
grid_df = pd.read_pickle('base_grids/main_grid.pkl') # this file about 200mb
```

Получаю:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\greg\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py in read_pickle(path, compression)
    154             warnings.simplefilter("ignore", Warning)
--> 155             return pickle.load(f)
    156     except Exception:  # noqa: E722

UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

Comment: А pickle той же версии которой записывали? А пробовали ещё раз записать, может файл побился?

Comment: Да, проблема была в том, что pickle другой версии, файл получен из другого окружения. Thx)